# Access properties of a parent class from a child class

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a parent class MainViewController that hosts two subclasses secondViewController and thirdViewController and I am trying to access a property `id` of MainViewController from  secondViewController like **`self`**`.parent!` because I need to store and save it into a delegate array globally to access it from another UIViewController

```
class MainViewController: {

 var id: Int

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.id = 0
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

//...other subclasses

}
```

```
class secondViewController: UIViewController {
    
  
 func savedFunc(){
        let uuid = UUID()

      // saved as a custom struct 
        let prop = viewControllerDictionary(id: uuid, view: self.parent!)
     
        //append into delegate 
        VCs.shared.storedVc.append(prop)
    }
 }
```

I tried creating an instance of `MainViewController` inside `secondViewController` VC like so

```
 weak var mainViewController: MainViewController?
```

And access it like this

```
mainViewController.id
```

But it does not work for me because I need to access the path of the current `MainViewController`  parent class not a new instance of it, since I am doing it from a child subclass.
Is there any way to kinda access it like `self.parent.id`? I know that is a syntax mistake but it is the only way I could think of accessing the current parent class property. How could I make it correctly?

Comment: Where is created `secondViewController` instance?

Comment: You need the main view controller to provide a reference to itself to the second view controller after it creates it `secondViewController.mainViewController = self`

Comment: If `MainViewController` creates and sets up `SecondViewController` and `ThirdViewController` then why not have `MainViewController` pass its `id` to the other controllers when it creates them? Then those other controllers don't need to know anything about `MainViewController`.

Comment: Please note that your question is a bit confusing. You don't show how `MainViewController` creates and sets up the other two controllers. And your `SecondViewController` references `parent` but you don't show us how that is implemented. Your question needs a lot of clarification.

Comment: While it wouldn't be a great solution you *could* use a `static` var on MainViewController that would allow you to get the desired `id` value without having to reference the specific instance.  Using a static var woudn't work if you're going to have multiple instances of `MainViewController` though.  You could add the var to your controller: `static var id: Int = 0` and then reference it from any class using `MainViewController.id` or from within MainViewController using `Self.id`.